# Landscape - Script error

Tags: landscape

I run a dedicated landscape server for personal use, but I can't run scripts?

I am getting this messagevery time :

> System error
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. This event has been logged.
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience. Please contact Canonical Support for >further assistance.
>
> OOPS ID: 3490DFA8

`Jul 23 23:45:54 appserver-1 ERR  https://Landscape/account/standalone/computers/update#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 132, in publish#012    result = publication.callObject(request, obj)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/app/publication/zopepublication.py", line 205, in callObject#012    return mapply(ob, request.getPositionalArguments(), request)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 107, in mapply#012    return debug_call(obj, args)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/publish.py", line 113, in debug_call#012    return obj(*args)#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/ui/selection/selection.py", line 110, in update#012    self.request.response.redirect(next_url)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/browser.py", line 759, in redirect#012    return super(BrowserResponse, self).redirect(location, status, trusted)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/publisher/http.py", line 886, in redirect#012    % target_host)#012ValueError: Untrusted redirect to host 'landscape:443' not allowed.
Jul 23 23:45:54 appserver-1 WARNING  Dumping OOPS 3490DFA10.`

Is there anyone with the knowlgede to resolve this ? i am able to create scripts but as soon as i choose wich server to execute it on i am getting this message

Comment: You seem to have hit a bug. Please attach the appserver logs here, they will contain the reason for the System Error. It's /var/log/landscape-server/appserver.log IIRC.

Comment: i have updated the Question. IIRC?

Answer (score 4):

You have a mismatch between the landscape root-url in the "LDS Settings" page and what you are actually using in your browser to access it.

Either change the way you access landscape in your browser (have it match what is in root-url currently), or change the root-url value. If the latter, you have to restart the landscape services after the change with "sudo lsctl restart" on the landscape machine(s).

Comment: i found it under /etc/landscape/service.conf and changed it to http://landscape:9100, i have also added 10.0.2.47 to /etc/hosts/ and it worked for like 2 min and then the error returned?

Comment: This is odd, i have a client setup and lets call it Ubuntu1.
If i enter - Computers -> Ubuntu1 in the browser then i can use all the functions from the tab but if i choose Computer -> and use the checkmark whre i can select more than one client and then want to go to script then the error will appear.

I have tried to do a fresh install without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Check the hostname throughout `/etc/apache2/site-enables/your-lusu-server.conf`

In mine part of the host was Capitalised.

it was like that in three places.

```
ServerName
ServerAdmin
RewriteRule
ServerAdmin
RewriteRule
RewriteRule
```

After changing it to all lower case, everything worked.