# Landscape "System error" when Monitoring multiple Computers

Tags: server, landscape

I'm using Landscape 15.11 on Ubutntu server 14.04. The server has 4 Computers registered with it, including itself.  When I use the web UI to look at a single computer, I can click Monitoring and get graphs for that computer.  However, if i select more than one computer (the check boxes shown after clicking Computers), then click Monitoring (or Activities, or Hardware or anything along the top menu) , I get  an error screen like this:

> System error An unexpected error has occurred. This event has been
>   logged.
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience. Please contact Canonical Support
>   for further assistance.
>
> OOPS ID: OOPS-22c10b9e67a3ae11c623ed9032527627

If I look at /var/log/landscape-server/async-frontend.log, I see initial 200 responses for the initial POST request followed by a delayed 408 response like the below.  Any clues at how to make the front end work as expected?

```
Mar 22 16:58:55 async-frontend-1 INFO  Consuming from queue '1bfc9353-b321-405b-be75-a261b8bf8598'

Mar 22 16:58:55 async-frontend-1 INFO  127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2016:23:58:54 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 153 "https://bot17/account/standalone/computers" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"

Mar 22 16:58:55 async-frontend-1 INFO  Consuming from queue '1bfc9353-b321-405b-be75-a261b8bf8598'

Mar 22 16:58:57 async-frontend-1 INFO  Consuming from queue '78ec127d-1173-4ba4-948b-644bfa55dd01'

Mar 22 16:58:57 async-frontend-1 INFO  127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2016:23:58:56 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 153 "https://bot17/account/standalone/computers/update" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"

Mar 22 16:58:57 async-frontend-1 INFO  Consuming from queue '78ec127d-1173-4ba4-948b-644bfa55dd01'

Mar 22 16:59:01 async-frontend-1 INFO  Consuming from queue '9c213177-9fa5-4984-8ae5-9559da35f5b4'

Mar 22 16:59:01 async-frontend-1 INFO  127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2016:23:59:00 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 153 "https://bot17/account/standalone/computers" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"

Mar 22 16:59:01 async-frontend-1 INFO  Consuming from queue '9c213177-9fa5-4984-8ae5-9559da35f5b4'

Mar 22 16:59:02 async-frontend-1 INFO  127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2016:23:59:02 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 408 - "https://bot17/account/standalone/computers" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"

Mar 22 16:59:08 async-frontend-1 INFO  127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2016:23:59:07 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 408 - "https://bot17/account/standalone/computers/update" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Can you paste appserver.log using http://paste.ubuntu.com and share the link?

Comment: Thanks @AdamCollard.  Here's the log paste: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15492829/

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't cover the time you hit the issue, please look through the rotated logs and find one which covers the time you had the problem (or reproduce the issue again)

Comment: Here's another paste.  I re-created the problem twice in a row just before pasting, so the end (~line 389) onward should be what's helpful. 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/15560696/

Comment: Hi @AdamCollard, just checking back in to see if the new paste above provides the info you needed?  Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue with 16.03 and this solved it:

[Landscape - Script error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651883/landscape-script-error)

It appears to be a bug where if the capitalization of the server name in the browser and configurations don't match with an error like yours:

Untrusted redirect to host ':443' not allowed.

Comment: thanks!  i've stopped using landscape since posting the problem, but I'll mark your comment as the answer because that makes sense give my hostnames.